# `sqlite3` ignores `sqlite3_busy_timeout`?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I use `sqlite3` in multiple threads application (it is compiled with `SQLITE_THREADSAFE=2`). In watch window I see that `sqlite->busyTimeout == 600000`, i. e. that it is supposed to have 10 minutes timeout. However, `sqlite3_step` returns `SQLITE_BUSY` obvoiusly faster than after 10 minutes (it returns instantly actually, like if I never called `sqlite3_busy_timeout`).
What is the reason that `sqlite3` ignores timeout and return error instantly?

Comment: Have you set the busy callback? Otherwise it will return directly upon encountering the lock!

Comment: @rfkortekaas `sqlite3_busy_timeout` does set the busy callback, as clearly stated in [the fine manual](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One possibility: SQLite ignores the timeout when it detects a deadlock.

The scenario is as follows. Transaction `A` starts as a reader, and later attempts to perform a write. Transaction `B` is a writer (either started that way, or started as a reader and promoted to a writer first). `B` holds a `RESERVED` lock, waiting for readers to clear so it can start writing. `A` holds a `SHARED` lock (it's a reader) and tries to acquire `RESERVED` lock (so it can start writing). For description of various lock types, see http://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

The only way to make progress in this situation is for one of the transactions to roll back. No amount of waiting will help, so when SQLite detects this situation, it doesn't honor the busy timeout.

There are two ways to avoid the possibility of a deadlock:

1. Switch to [WAL mode](http://sqlite.org/wal.html) - it allows one writer to co-exist with multiple readers.
2. Use `BEGIN IMMEDIATE` to start a transaction that may eventually need to write - this way, it starts as a writer right away. This of course reduces the potential concurrency in the system, as the price of avoiding deadlocks.

Comment: How does sqlite3 distinguish between readers and writers? I just send SQL commands from various threads using SELECT, INSERT or REMOVE with sqlite3_prepare_v2, sqlite3_step and sqlite3_finalize. If I run the same program twice, accessing the same database, then how can there be a deadlock? It is because INSERT or REMOVE start with RESERVED and then escalate to EXCLUSIVE? Why can't they go to EXCLUSIVE right away?

Comment: @Fabian `How does sqlite3 distinguish between readers and writers?` By the statements the transaction executes, of course. You read with `SELECT`, you write with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` (roughly; there are also things like `CREATE TABLE` which are obviously writing; and things like `PRAGMA table_info` which are reading).

Comment: @Fabian `INSERT or REMOVE start with RESERVED and then escalate to EXCLUSIVE? Why can't they go to EXCLUSIVE right away?` Have you read the article I linked to? It explains why. Basically, a transaction cannot proceed straight to `EXCLUSIVE` lock when there's another transaction that is also reading or writing the same database. At any one time on a given database file, there may be multiple readers OR a single writer (in journal mode); or multiple readers AND a single writer (in WAL mode). Locks are used to maintain this invariant.

Answer (score -2):

I made a lot of tests and share them here for other people who uses `SQLite` in multithreaded environment. `SQLite` threading support is not well documented, there are not any good tutorial that describes all threading issues in one place. I made a test program that creates 100 threads and sends random queries (`INSERT`, `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) concurrently to single database. My answer is based on this program observation.

The only really thread safe journal mode is `WAL`. It allows multiple connections to do anything they need for the same database within one proces in the same manner as single threaded application does. Any other modes are not thread safe independently from timeouts, busy handlers and `SQLITE_THREADSAFE` preprocessor definition. They generate `SQLITE_BUSY` periodically, and it looks like complex programming task to expect such error always and handle it always. If you need thread safe `SQLite` that never returns `SQLITE_BUSY` like signle thread does, you have to set `WAL` journal mode.

Additionally, you have to set `SQLITE_THREADSAFE=2` or `SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1` preprocessor definition.

When done, you have to choose from 2 options:

1. You can call `sqlite3_busy_timeout`. It is enough, you are not required to call `sqlite3_busy_handler`, even from documentation it is not obvious. It gives you "default", "built-in" timeout functionality.
2. You can call `sqlite3_busy_handler` and implement timeout yourself. I don't see why, but may be under some nonstandard OS it is required. When you call `sqlite3_busy_handler`, it resets timeout to 0 (i. e. disabled). For desktop `Linux` & `Windows` you don't need it unless you like to write more complex code.

Comment: WAL mode can throw `SQLITE_BUSY` as well, if t1 reads from a database, t2 inserts to the database, and t1 tries to insert to the database. Additionally, calling it "not thread safe" is a bit extreme; "not thread safe" usually implies undefined behavior, but SQLite fails gracefully.

Comment: Well, may be `SQLITE_BUSY` is possible, however, when it never occurred during a hour with 100 threads application that sends random queries, probability is not high. And I think "thread safe" means that library works without problems on as many threads as application requires. Graceful failure is also failure. Try to explain to end user that his data is not saved because of graceful failure ;)